# Bind data to Custom TextBox C#

Tags: c#, data-binding, binding, overriding, 2-way-object-databinding

I written a class named `MoneyTextBox` that inherits `TextBox`.

Everything is OK but where I'm trying to bind data to the `Text` property of my `MoneyTextBox`.

In the form which I used to bind data to its controls, even reading data is OK! I mean when the data from bindingSource bound to the form, everything working correctly. But when I'm trying to `Update` the tableAdapter, null value went to the database!

Here is `MoneyTextBox` class:

```
class MoneyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public override string Text
    {
        set
        {
            base.Text = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return skipComma(base.Text);
        }
    }

    public string skipComma(string str)
    {
        string strnew = "";
        if (str == "")
        {
            strnew = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            strnew = str.Replace(",", String.Empty);
        }
        return strnew;
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (base.Text == "")
        {
            this.Text = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.Text != "")
            {
                double d;
                if (!Double.TryParse(this.Text, out d))
                {
                    this.Text = null;
                    return;
                }
                if (d == 0)
                {
                    this.Text = "0";
                }
                else
                    this.Text = d.ToString("#,#", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
        this.Select(this.TextLength, 0);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar < 48 || e.KeyChar > 57) && e.KeyChar != 8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control & e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            this.SelectAll();
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Any idea? If it's necessary to more explain, tell me guys. Thanks in advance...